# cordova-plugin-file does not work well in browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I am now developing an cordova app which is on platform browser. But I met a problem when using cordova-plugin-file to read a local file. My browser always get an "adding proxy for File" and a "Persistent fs quota granted" in my chrome console.

[screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uuSl.png)

I download an example from Cordova-Examples-master in github, but it comes in the same situation. So it seems like a wrong setting bug not bug in my code.

Have anyone met this problem before?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should actually work as the Chrome init issue has been recently [fixed](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/commit/77c63ef181313eba51652e1026cc730fc79ab9f2). Can you post error messages you got when trying to read the file? Can you add the plugin via git url: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git`? If not please paste the CLI error output as well.

Comment: @daserge Yes, I tried a lot yesterday, and get the latest version of cordova-plugin-file. But it still didn't work. There is no CLI error, but I get a little further information about the error in my console. I asked about that in another question:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283600/encodingerror-when-cordova-plugin-file). If you are interested in the question or have any experience, please take look of that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova app should run from WebView control embedded to native mobile Cordova-based application with corresponding plugins compiled. It will not properly work in standalone web-browser, neither on PC nor mobile device.