# EncodingError when cordova-plugin-file

Tags: cordova, html5-filesystem, cordova-plugin-file

I am now developing a cordova app which platform is browser.

I need to access a text file from local file system, so I am using the cordova-plugin-file.

But I failed as the exception in my chrome console like this (There is no CLI error):

> code: 5
>
> message: "A URI supplied to the API was malformed, or the resulting Data URL has exceeded the URL length limitations for Data URLs."
>
> name: "EncodingError"

as my code blow:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', dataRead, false);
    function dataRead() {
      window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 100500*1024*1024, function() {
        window.webkitResolveLocalFileSystemURL("filesystem:" + cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "1111.csv", gotFile, fail);
      },function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
    function fail(e) {
      console.log("FileSystem Error");
      console.dir(e);
    }

    function gotFile(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          console.log("Text is: "+this.result);
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);
      });

    }
```

Is my URI illegal or for some other reasons?

Can anybody point out why? Or show me a right example.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good reference point for the file plugin are [its auto and manual tests](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/tests/tests.js), which can be run in [cordova-plugin-test-framework](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-test-framework) and also [the file plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).

A few points on your question:

- try to use something less than `100500*1024*1024`, for example `10*1024*1024`,
- instead of

`window.webkitResolveLocalFileSystemURL("filesystem:" + cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "1111.csv", gotFile, fail);`

try to use

`window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("filesystem:" + cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "persistent/1111.csv", gotFile, fail);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your suggestions, but still failed with a same error message. As I read the  [cordova-plugin-document: Chrome quirks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#chrome-quirks)  ,It said that:  **Chrome filesystem is not immediately ready after device ready event.....You can use `window.isFilePluginReadyRaised` function to check whether event was already raised.**  And after I checked about this I found the `filePluginIsReady` event is never fired. Do you have any suggestions about this? Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, I raise another question about this. If you have any interest or time, you can go there and have a look [filePluginIsReady event is never fired in chrome when using cordova-plugin-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328734/filepluginisready-event-is-never-fired-in-chrome-when-using-cordova-plugin-file) .Thank you very much.

Comment: @SimonBai, I realized that there is a quirk for browser platform that `filesystem:` prefix is required - and you also need to specify the FS type in the path - please try the updated answer.

Comment: Oops，I have tried to add a `filesystem:` before, but didn't tried `persistent`.As I  will try it after the weekend:) Good weekend!