# filePluginIsReady event is never fired in chrome when using cordova-plugin-file

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, cordova-plugins, html5-filesystem, cordova-plugin-file

I am now developing a cordova app whitch platform is browser(Chrome).

I failed when using the cordova-plugin-file to read a file.

According to the document of [cordova-plugin-file : Chrome quirks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#chrome-quirks), It said that:

**Chrome filesystem is not immediately ready after device ready event. As a workaround you can subscribe to `filePluginIsReady` event....You can use `window.isFilePluginReadyRaised` function to check whether event was already raised.**

I wrote my code like this :

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', dataRead, false);
function dataRead() {
  window.addEventListener('filePluginIsReady', readyToRead, false);
  console.log(window.isFilePluginReadyRaised());
}

function readyToRead(){
  window.initPersistentFileSystem(10*1024*1024, function() {
    var fs = cordova.file.applicationDirectory;
    console.log(fs);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/1111.csv", gotFile, fail);
  },function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
}

function fail(e) {
  console.log("FileSystem Error");
  console.dir(e);
}

function gotFile(fileEntry) {
  fileEntry.file(function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
      console.log("Text is: "+this.result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
}
```

It failed to read the file, and the message in console likes this:

> adding proxy for File ------------------cordova.js:942
>
> Persistent fs quota granted ---------Preparing.js:170
>
> false --------------------------------------app.js:4 (value of `window.isFilePluginReadyRaised()`)

**It seems that `filePluginIsReady` event didn't fired! WHY?**

Besides, if I write my code under the `deviceready` event directly. It will also fail with error message below:

> code: 5
>
> message: "A URI supplied to the API was malformed, or the resulting Data URL has exceeded the URL length limitations for Data URLs."
>
> name: "EncodingError"

Can any one point out why or show me a right example?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution? Thanks.

Comment: It finally works after closing the Chrome instance opened by cordova run browser and restarting

Answer (score 1):

one thing why this could have happened  is that probably the time you attached to the filePluginIsReady the event was already fired. Try to subscribe to the event in the appStart.js or the first file in your app. It worked for me